# Excel 2007 VBA - Pivot table field list??? creates error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

---

Last update on October 14, 2011 - I know more info now, so I will summarize everything here and delete all my previous descriptions/questions.

The problem is, after running a certain program, I get some weird error.  It's similar to, but not exactly like, when I click "Split".  The difference is the solid gray bars do not show up.  It's sort of weird.  More recently, I have started thinking it is probably caused by the field list of the pivot tables involved.

The problem occurs with any of the three following pieces of code

Code 1

```
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
For Each pvtCache In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
    pvtCache.Refresh
Next pvtCache
```

Code 2

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Code 3

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
Next ws
```

But not with this, where the only difference is I added ws.Activate to Code 3

Code 4

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
Next ws
```

So, my question is, can any one explain this?  Can any one fix Code 1 (which is much faster in a spreadsheet with 2 pivot caches from large data sources, but 46 pivot tables) to make it work without this error?

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: we can't guess without seeing the code and you can't post it so... Well, anyway, you can still set some breakpoints in your code (and comment any `screenupdating` set to false) and see where (while setting breakpoints in several lines of your code) the split appear. That would probably help you focus on the "wrong" lines

Comment: Not sure why you're reluctant to post your code: is your company worried we'll copy your secret bug?  We all post "work" code here...

Comment: Can you refresh all the pivot tables "manually"?  My hunch is that you cannot.

Comment: @adamleerich I'm sorry, I don't understand.  Do you mean, without code?  I can try that, but it would be a big pain and it's not a good long term solution.  Or do you mean to instead refresh each pivot table in the code, as opposed to the above which refreshes each pivotcache?  The thing is, there are 46 pivot tables in the worksheet with only 2 pivotcaches, so it would do 44 extra refreshes, which does take around 45 seconds of time.  But, that probably would be better than this weird screen thing.

Comment: "The problem is, after running a certain program, I get some weird error." - What exactly is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple pivots from multiple sheets and all three code snippets works fine. There should be something else causing the problem, its not the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippets run correctly.

It could be that the screen display may not be refreshing after your code is run.

Try adding this round your code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ''//Your code here
DoEvents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```